# Github pull without a pull request

Tags: github

On github, how is it possible for the owner of an original repository to **pull the changes that were made in a fork by another user, without a pull request**? Or anyway include the fork's changes into the original repository, maintaining information about the fork's author?

Should I clone the fork and then push it to the original repository?
Or I could copy them manually, but that wouldn't be fair at all, because the project would lose any information about the fork's changes author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the normal distributed workflow of Git here. That is, add the other repository as a second remote to your local repository, and then simply merge their changes in.

```
git remote add others-fork https://github.com/otheruser/fork.git
git fetch others-fork

git checkout master
git merge others-fork/master
```

This would merge the changes from their master into your local master. Afterwards, you can push your changes to publish their commits in your repository.

Comment: is this considered legitimate and will the fork's author remain visible and become a collaborator?

Comment: This will use the exact commit objects that exist within the fork, so yeah, all author and comitter information from the fork will be left intact. The effect should actually be the same as if they submitted a pull request and you merged them there; it’s just that the source is a different one now.